# How to get bookshelf model from multiple tables at once

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I'm developing a node.js web service that looks like an auction. I'm using  bookshelf.js for models and MySQL as DB. 
Please consider the following db structure:

```
users:
id     |     login     |     password     |
users_roles:
id     |     user_id     |     role_id          |
roles:
id      |     name     |
auctions:
id      |     user_id     |     rating_id     |
rating:
id      |     speed     |     quality          |     communication     |
```

Currently I have implemented User model as follows:

```
 var Bookshelf = require('./bookshelf_model'),
    Role = require("./role");

var User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'users',

        role: function () {
            return this.belongsToMany(Role, 'users_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
        }
    });

module.exports = User;
```

I can get user details by

```
User.forge({id: 1}).fetch().then(
      function(userDetails){
          .......
      }
    );
```

This returns users' details from users table. To get user role I have to do yet another db call, like:

```
User.forge({id: 1}).role().fetch().then(
      function(userRoleDetails){
          .....
      }
    );
```

Is there any method to get all user info at once using bookshelf.js (or by using anythig else)? It would be great to get something like that at once:

```
user={
 id:...,
 login:...,
 password:...,
 role_id:....,
 rating:/*avg rating from all user's auctions*/
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

`return User.forge( {
      id: 1
    } )
    .fetch( {
      require: true, //throws error if not found
      withRelated: [ 'role' ]
    } )
    .then( function( userModel ) {
      return userModel.toJSON(); //don't need this step, depends what you want to do next
    } )`

Something like that. This will load the `user_roles` object into the User, with the `role` property. Some documentation [here](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-fetch)

Comment: This is not what I tried to achieve, this solves roles problem but more complex fields require anything else to be done. I came with the following solution: get rid of bookshelf and wrap everything I need into stored procedures (like get user details by login), this allow me to get anything in one SP call. Works great

Comment: Yeah, SP is another approach. Glad you got it working!